# I can only download for an hour with App Testers

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-app-distribution

Good afternoon!
Please tell me, I ran into a problem: I'm uploading the application to AppTesters (AppDistribution) for Android. There are invited testers and they can successfully download the application - BUT only during the first hour!!!
After one hour from the moment of pouring the application, it is no longer available for download and when trying to download it gives an error "Error downloading the release".
In the logs of the device at this moment such an error.
Previously everything worked and did not change any settings.
What are the problems?

2022-10-24 09:45:43.098 31041-31090/? E/AppDownloadService: Error downloading the aab - [https://firebaseapptesters.googleapis.com/v1alpha/devices/9227b7ed1da4a1998db84131/testerApps/1:840168565760:android:ce3748d8ea0599b0b63ce5/releases/7kmehhnltmpk0:download?tester_client=android_tester_app&token=AFb1MRwAAAAA>>>](https://firebaseapptesters.googleapis.com/v1alpha/devices/9227b7ed1da4a1998db84131/testerApps/1:840168565760:android:ce3748d8ea0599b0b63ce5/releases/7kmehhnltmpk0:download?tester_client=android_tester_app&token=AFb1MRwAAAAA%3E%3E%3E). Response code - vary: Origin
vary: X-Origin
vary: Referer
content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
date: Mon, 24 Oct 2022 06:45:41 GMT
server: ESF
cache-control: private
x-xss-protection: 0
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
x-content-type-options: nosniff
alt-svc: h3=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43"

Response:
{
"error": {
"code": 400,
"message": "Precondition check failed.",
"status": "FAILED_PRECONDITION"
}
}

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: An hour after the publication, I can not download the application - an error occurs